# Copying an array with references; how to get the values only

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I was messing with arrays and references, when I came across an interesting problem.  Take this code, for example:

```
// Set everything up
$testArray = array(
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array()
);

$saved = array();

$ref =& $testArray['b'];

// Set a value via the reference
$ref = array(1);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?

// Set another value via the reference
$ref = array(2);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?
```

Nothing too complicated.  It makes an array, and a reference to a "deep value" in the array.

When I `var_dump($saved)`, the result is not what I expect!  I get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    &array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    &array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

I thought arrays were copied by value, not reference.  Why is `[b]` equal to `array(2)` in both spots?  How can I copy an array and break its references?

I want the result to be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Why is `$ref` still linked to a *copy* of the `$testArray` array?  I want to basically save the "state" of the array, and have the reference only update the original and not the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains arrays' references, if you copy your array, the sub-arrays are just references... you need a deep copy. Make a recursive function:

```
function cloneArray($array){
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value))
            $value = cloneArray($value);

        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

this should work for your needs

Comment: I figured out that `$saved[] = array_map(function($a){ return $a; }, $testArray);` would work.  This seems like a better version of that.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. You can use the function `debug_zval_dump()` to see that indeed the refcounter to the index `b` is `2`.

```
// Set everything up
$testArray = array(
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array()
);

$saved = array();

$ref =& $testArray['b'];

// Set a value via the reference
$ref = array(1);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?
debug_zval_dump($saved[0]);

// Set another value via the reference
$ref = array(2);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?
```

What gives you:

```
array(2) refcount(3){
  ["a"]=>
  array(0) refcount(1){
  }
  ["b"]=>
  &array(1) refcount(2){
    [0]=>
    long(1) refcount(1)
  }
}
```

---

If you want to circumvent this behaviour you need to unset the reference and get a new one before modifying it:

```
// Set everything up
$testArray = array(
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array()
);

$saved = array();

$ref =& $testArray['b'];

// Set a value via the reference
$ref = array(1);
unset($ref);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?
debug_zval_dump($saved[0]);

$ref =& $testArray['b'];
// Set another value via the reference
$ref = array(2);
unset($ref);

// Save the current array state
$saved[] = $testArray; // This shouldn't be a reference, right?

var_dump($saved);
```

However, this is just theoretical stuff. You can of course do it easier without using references at all.

Comment: The problem is when I do `$saved[] = $testArray;`, the reference is still linked.  How can I break the reference when I copy the array?

Comment: Do you mean the `&array` in the var_dump output? I used PHP 5.3  for testing this. In my output there is no `&array`

Comment: But in your output, were both values of `[b]` equal to `array(2)`?  I want to basically save the "state" of the array, and have the reference only update the original and not the copy.

Comment: But however, it looks as expected behaviour for me. Will try to find some documentation for you

Comment: There's got to be a way to copy the array and break the references.  Even if I need to loop over it or use `array_merge_recursive`.

Comment: The documentation says: Array assignment always involves value copying. It also means that the internal array pointer used by current() and similar functions is reset. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference. ... This would make me think that this is really unexpected behaviour..

Comment: Well, references are a two-way street.  The `$testArray` contains a reference to $ref` (if I update `$testArray['b']`, `$ref` gets "updated").  So when `$testArray` is copied, so is the reference it contains.

Comment: Check my update. :) After thinking `3` times over it, it is expected behaviour for me. At least it can be explained using the `debug_zval_dump()` function.

Comment: So, is there any way to get what I want?  :)   My actual code has a big `foreach` that moves and sets the `$ref`, so unsetting and resetting the reference wouldn't work.  I want to just unset the reference after I copy the array into `$saved`.

Comment: I could do that, but the major issue is that my reference is set via a `foreach` loop, so it would be tough to re-set it.  I tried something and it seemed to work: `$saved[] = array_map(function($a){ return $a; }, $testArray);`

Comment: The `array_map()` trick should work. You should consider to post it as an answer. Of course it is not good for performance but I don't know your exact application needs

Comment: Good performance would be nice, but for now, I'd like to get it working.

Comment: This reference stuff in PHP should being used with care. Often it makes more trouble than it brings benefits. You should use them only if you *really* need them for your logic